# Can't find command, although it is in the PATH

Tags: bash

I just [installed](https://gist.github.com/oo00spy00oo/abe9769f22aa7963e601) git on CentOS 6.8. When I run the command `git` from a bash-shell, I get the following error message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/git: Bestand of map bestaat niet
```

Sorry, Dutch installation. Meaning: "File or folder doesn't exist". Git *is* installed.

When I run `/usr/local/bin/git --version`, I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/git: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/git)
git version 2.5.3
```

(not sure if the libz message is a problem).

`which git` points to `/usr/local/bin/git`, so that's fine too. `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`. I've looked for aliases and other clues in `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and `/etc/bashrc`, but nothing...

How can I run git with just entering the command `git`?

Comment: Have you ever run `git` before while it was in `/usr/bin`?  If you run `type git` what do you see?

Comment: Yes! I've installed it first with `yum`, but that was git version 1.7. `type git` says `git is gehasht (/usr/bin/git)`. Some hash cache? How do I clear it?

Comment: As the other question talks about, bash will cache locations of files it's used so it doesn't have to search the path each time, included there are instructions to either clear a specific file (`git` here) or the entire cache

Answer (score 2):

Make a symbolic link between `/usr/bin/git` and `/usr/local/bin/git`

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution. I could also create an alias. But I would rather understand what is going on. Thanks for the answer though. Didn't think of this solution. (I swapped target and link name in your example, but it only shows when it's peer reviewed).

Comment: I'm ALWAYS having this issue with `ln` ... Thanks for the correction.